# Single Page application with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, single-page-application

I am pretty new to SPA.  I'd like to known if it is possible to build a SPA with only Bootstrap or I have to use a framework like Jquery mobile or angular ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`Bootstrap` is CSS, HTML and JavaScript Framework which contains HTML- and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions.

To Build a SPA application you have to use JavaScript libraries or Frameworks.

From http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework/ you can get an idea of SPA without javascript frameworks.

There are a lot of open source JavaScript frameworks that help with building SPA, such as:

- Angular
- React
- Ember
- Aurelia
- Vue.js
- Cycle.js
- Backbone

Answer (score 2):

You have to use JS framework.

Bootstrap is only CSS framework. It makes your application looks better. Ok, you can use custom datepickers, modals etc, but usually this functionalities are implemented in CSS frameworks like Boostrap by jQuery. You can check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) page to confirm it. You need JS framework for SPA (or create a new one).